# Shadowing in F#

Tags: math, f#, algebra, purely-functional, shadowing

I'm wondering why F# allows shadowing, particularly within the same scope.

I've always thought of value binding in purely functional programming constructs as being akin to assignments in algebra/mathematics.

So for example,

y = x + 1

will be a valid mathematical expression but

y = y + 1

won't be.

However, because of shadowing,

`let y = y + 1`

is a perfectly valid expression in F#.

Why does the language allow this?

Comment: `y = y + 1` isn't a valid algebraic expression, but here it's akin to `y' = y + 1`. The original `y` is no longer accessible because of shadowing. It's not actually mutating `y`, but reusing the binding's name.

Comment: Interesting question, but since it's a conceptual, discussion question, it seems more on-topic for cs.stackexchange.com instead of SO which is for specific programming questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most correct answer to this is because the creator, Don Syme, felt that it was a useful feature to add to the language.

There are some good uses for it, though. One is when working with F#-style optional parameters:

```
type C() =
    member _.M(?x) =
        let x = Option.defaultValue 0 x
        printfn "%d" x
```

F# optional parameters are options, which brings a high degree of correctness and consistency. But imagine having 3 or more optional parameters to a method. It would get annoying to have to rebind the value for each of them and use a different name for them! This is one area where shadowing comes in handy.

It's also handy when writing recursive subroutines. Consider the following naiive implementation of `sum` for a list:

```
let mySum xs =
    let rec loop xs acc =
        match xs with
        | [] -> acc
        | h :: t -> loop t (h + acc)
    loop xs 0
```

I don't need to rebind `xs` for the inner loop because of shadowing. Since it's generic, `xs` is about as good of a name as I can come up with, so it would be annoying to have had to use a different name for the inner loop.

Shadowing isn't all good news, though. If you're not careful, types from one `open` declaraction can shadow types from one that was declared previously. This can be confusing. F# editor tooling can distinguish bindings from the ones that shadow them, but you don't get that with plain text. So the bottom line is: think carefully when applying shadowing in F#.